# JQuery change class name inside of specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for JQuery script to change a tag class inside of specific tags.

For example,

```
<h4 class=" id_1">
    <span class="favorite"> </span>
</h4>
```

In above tags, I want to change  `class="favorite"` to `class="title"` by **id_1** class.
CSS for favorite and title is different.

Thank you!

Comment: Working example: https://jsbin.com/sepunexaca/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

```
$(".id_1").removeClass("favourite").addClass("title");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method:

```
$('.id_1 .favorite').attr('class','title');
```

---

Using JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('.id_1 .favorite').setAttribute('class','title');
```

Comment: _Using JavaScript_ is nice :) I would go with the `.className`->(properties over attributes)

Comment: Yeah, there are many ways we do coding...I have shown to use attr method in jquery so used setAttribute in javascript..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` to achieve this:

```
$('.id_1 .favorite').removeClass('favorite').addClass('title');
```

You could also use `toggleClass` if you can guarantee the starting state of the relevant elements:

```
$('.id_1 .favorite').toggleClass('favorite title');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.id_1 .favorite').removeClass('favourite').addClass('title');
```